# Is it ok to ignore data in this instance?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, computational-statistics

I'm running a program in python I wrote to look at the first spiking time of a neuron in a stochastic network. I'm running about 2500 realizations for each set of parameter values to calculate the mean spike time and coefficient of variation.

The program will run a simulation over a time interval [0,200 ms], records the first time it detects a spike, and then creates a big data table of all the first response times. If a spike does not occur, then it just reads it as NaN (not a number) -- NaN occur because the program does not detect a spike over the specified time interval (a spike is defined in the program when the SDE describing my voltage reaches a certain threshold).

I've been plotting a histogram and calculating mean and CV by ignoring the NaN values. For most of these plots, out of 2500 realizations, usually only 1 or 2 realizations resulted in NaN, so dropping them wasn't really a big deal. However, in a more recent simulation, I decreased the noise level and this resulted in a bigger change in spiking time.

Under one set of conditions, I got 2 NaN values out of 2500, and computed Mean and variance as follows:

Mean = 32.493326661329057
Variance = 733.42170274437331

Under the other (with lower noise strength), I got 196 NaN values out of 2500, and the following:

Mean = 64.072560763888887
Variance = 2266.1796512549886

So I have two questions:

1. Is it ok to compute mean and CV by ignoring the 196 NaN values? I wasn't sure as it seemed like a lot of data to ignore
2. Am I better off increasing the simulation time to say [0,300]? The tradeoff is that the computation time is quite a bit longer, but I would assume the results would be comparable to the first case where only 2 were NaN if on this longer time scale, only a couple were NaN as well?

Comment: Can you trace where the NaNs are coming from? Why do they occur?

Comment: @gung They occur because the program does not detect a spike over the specified time interval (a spike is defined in the program when the SDE describing my voltage reaches a certain threshold)

Comment: This all seems to hinge on "If a spike does not occur, then it just reads it as NaN (not a number)". Why doesn't a spike occur? If the reason is that you didn't wait long enough to see one, then there is a small bias in ignoring the NaNs. If NaN means essentially very high indeed, you can still work with medians and trimmed means.

Comment: Incidentally, and ignoring the implausible number of d.p. given!,  your coefficient of variation is about 83% in the first case and about 42% in the second case. When CV is so high, I tend to want to look at other summary measures too. When CV is so labile, it is more dubious as a natural measure.

Comment: That's critical information. Please add that to the description of your situation in the body of your question so that it isn't buried in the comments. You have **censoring**. Ignoring it in calculating means, etc, will lead to large biases.

Comment: @NickCox I can't prove it formally, but a spike likely doesn't occur because the time interval isn't long enough (since about 2300/2500 did occur in that time interval, it's certainly spiking). I had originally set 200ms as the cutoff for computational efficiency since losing only 1-2 data points out of 2500 didn't seem like it would lead to large bias

Comment: @gung I've added it, thank you. I had never heard of censoring in statistics. It sounds like I should let the time interval run longer, at least until the number of NaN values is extremely small.

Comment: @gung is right: the bias could be large. "small" was wrong.